# Cannot get a different Icon in Google map on change event

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new to Google API V3. I want to change the Icon on Zoom event. The full code is running as expected, it is the last bit wherein I have given a map change event to capture the change in zoom so that I could change in the icon from a simple circle to Google standard red icon. Please do review and suggest corrections, thank you so much.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="util.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var infowindow;
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(20, 0);
    var myOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    panControl:true,
    zoomControl:true,
    mapTypeControl:true,
    scaleControl:true,
    streetViewControl:true,
    overviewMapControl:true,
    rotateControl:true,    
    center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 }
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
downloadUrl("worldcities.xml", function(data) {
  var markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
var circleOptions = {
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.65,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.25,
    map: map,
    center: latlng,
    radius: parseInt(markers[i].getAttribute("population"))/25
    };

    var marker = createMarker(markers[i].getAttribute("name"), latlng,         markers[i].getAttribute("population"), markers[i].getAttribute("countrycode"), markers[i].getAttribute("region"));
var onekmcircle = new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions);
}
 });
}

function createMarker(name, latlng, popl, cntry, rgon) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: latlng, 
map: map,
icon: {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
scale: 2

    }, 
title: name});
var contentstring = '<b>'+name+'</b>'+'<br>Population: '+popl+'<br>Country: '+cntry+'<br>Region: '+rgon;


google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
  if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: contentstring});
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
  var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
  map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
  if (zoomLevel<6)
{
    map.setZoom(6);

}

});



return marker;
}

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {

var url ='http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png';
var icon = google.maps.MarkerImage(url);
var currentZoom = map.getZoom();
  if (currentZoom >9){
for(i=0; i< markers.length; i++ ) {
    markers[i].setIcon(icon);

   }
}
});
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly?  A fiddle would be helpful.

Comment: Problem is in the last change event, it is not changing the icon to red-dot.png on zooming the map to higher than 9 zoom levels. So please review this code snippet:-      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {

var url ='http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png';
var icon = google.maps.MarkerImage(url);
var currentZoom = map.getZoom();
  if (currentZoom >9){
for(i=0; i< markers.length; i++ ) {
    markers[i].setIcon(icon);

   }
}
});

Comment: I have uploaded the script on http://www.mapsandlocations.com/google/worldcities.htm and you can zoom in to see that the change of icon does not happen at higher zoom levels. so please help me in finding the code sequence which is not executing. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried doing some console.log's inside your event listener?  I would start there. Figure out what code is executing, and what code isn't.

Comment: I tried and found markers[i].setIcon(icon); is not executing but why I do not know. I am defining the path. I will try to read through the API documentation. Thanks.

Comment: So what is the last thing that is executed?  Do you get a log inside of `if (currentZoom >9){`?  and what about logging inside of the for loop?

Comment: On more analysis the zoom eventlistner is not firing on zoom event. so  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() { is not firing on zoom change, so the code within it is not executing. But why eventlistner even is not firing I do not know.... Is it a DOM event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go...I fixed your code for you...you had a few errors.  Biggest one being that you were not saving the markers you created into an array to loop through on the event listener.

I added the gMarkers array.  I ran the code in the console of your site and it worked.  Let me know if you have any questions.

```
 var infowindow;
 var map;
 var gMarkers=[];

  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(20, 0);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        panControl:true,
        zoomControl:true,
        mapTypeControl:true,
        scaleControl:true,
        streetViewControl:true,
        overviewMapControl:true,
        rotateControl:true,    
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    downloadUrl("worldcities.xml", function(data) {
        markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
        var circleOptions = {
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.65,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.25,
            map: map,
            center: latlng,
            radius: parseInt(markers[i].getAttribute("population"))/25
        };

        gMarkers.push(createMarker(markers[i].getAttribute("name"), latlng,markers[i].getAttribute("population"), markers[i].getAttribute("countrycode"), markers[i].getAttribute("region")));
        var onekmcircle = new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions);    
    }


    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
        var url ='http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png';
        var icon = google.maps.MarkerImage(url);
        var currentZoom = map.getZoom();
          if (currentZoom >9){
            for(var i=0; i< gMarkers.length; i++ ) {
                gMarkers[i].setIcon(icon);
            }
          }else{
                for(var i=0; i< gMarkers.length; i++ ) {
                    gMarkers[i].setIcon({path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,scale: 2});
                }
          }
    });

 }


function createMarker(name, latlng, popl, cntry, rgon) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng, 
        map: map,
        icon: {
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            scale: 2

        }, 
        title: name
    });

    var contentstring = '<b>'+name+'</b>'+'<br>Population: '+popl+'<br>Country: '+cntry+'<br>Region: '+rgon;

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: contentstring});
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        if (zoomLevel<6){
            map.setZoom(6);
        }
    });

    return marker;
}
```

Comment: Wow, great and thanks for doing the edits. The zoom event was not getting caught because it was out of initialise code.

Answer (score 0):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,\'mouseover\', function() {
    marker.setIcon("fileadmin/new_templates/images/home_map_notification_hover.png");
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async : false,
    data: \'address=\'+add ,
    success: function(html){

            infowindow.setContent(html); 
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        },
    });
});
// On Mouse out
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, \'mouseout\', function () {
marker.setIcon("fileadmin/new_templates/images/home_page_map_notification.png");
});
// On Infowindow close
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, \'closeclick\', function () {
marker.setIcon("fileadmin/new_templates/images/home_page_map_notification.png");
});
```